# How could one have particles emitted when two objects meet?

Tags: geometry-nodes, objects, particles, collision

In blender I want to be able to have a splash effect when a boat is in the water (a cube intersecting a plane essentially). I was thinking for this effect it could be that when these objects touch, small cube particles are emitted from the contact points, but I don't know how to do this, I have looked into geometry nodes but cannot find a way to do this, could anyone put me in the right direction? Or perhaps give me a better idea.
Thanks in advance.